# Comparing two arrays which have very dispersed values

Tags: python, scipy, histogram, normalization, binning

I have a very sparse array that looks like:

```
Array A: min = -68093253945.0 max=8.54631971208e+13
Array B: min=-1e+15 max = 1.87343e+14
```

And also each array will have concentration at certain levels e.g. near 2000, near 1m, near 0.05 and so on.

I am trying to compare these two arrays in terms of concentration, and want to do so in a way that is invariant to the number of entries in each. I also want to account for huge outliers if possible and maybe compress the bins to be between 0 and 1 or something of this sort.

The aim is to make a histogram via:

```
plt.hist(A,alpha=0.5,label='A')  # plt.hist passes it's arguments to np.histogram
ion()
plt.hist(B,alpha=0.5,label='B')
plt.title("Histogram of Values")
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.savefig('valuecomp.png')
```

How do I do this? I have experimented with:

```
A = stats.zscore(A)
B = stats.zscore(B)

A = preprocessing.scale(A)
B = preprocessing.scale(B)

A = preprocessing.scale(A, axis=0, with_mean=True, with_std=True, copy=True)
B = preprocessing.scale(B, axis=0, with_mean=True, with_std=True, copy=True)
```

And then for my histograms, adding `normed=True`, `range(0,100)`. All the methods give me a histogram with a massive vertical chunk near to 0.0 instead of distributing the values smoothly. `range(0,100)` looks good but it ignores any values like 1m outside of 100.

Perhaps I need to remove outliers from my data first and then do a histogram?

Comment: What language is this? Are you using python with SciPy?  Please edit your tags.

Comment: @ebyrob done. This is in python, I am also using `matplotlib.pyplot` and `sklearn.preprocessing`.

Comment: What about some non-constant/dynamic bin-width histogram like [this](http://www.astroml.org/user_guide/density_estimation.html#bayesian-blocks-histograms-the-right-way) (from astroml, also available in astropy)?

Answer (score 0):

@sascha's suggestion of using AstroML was a good one, but the `knuth` and `freedman` versions seem to take astronomically long (excuse the pun), and the `blocks` version simply thinned the blocks.

I took the sigmoid of each value via `from scipy.special import expit` and then plotted the histogram that way. Only way I could get this to work.